# How Return to the App Login screen when resuming an app from background?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have an app with multiple views. I would like the app to present to login screen whenever the app is resumed from background. How can I do this?
I was trying to modify the AppDelegate.swift but I didn't know which code should I add to switch the view.

(Code below doesn't work)

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    let vc: AnyObject? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginSID")
    self.presentViewController(vc as UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code from one of my own applications that does this very thing. It shows an authentication screen any time the user switches out and comes back. Obviously not all of it may be relevant to you, but I'll bet a lot of it is. If you'd like I can share more and show how I implemented the AuthViewController and such as well.

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
  var window: UIWindow?
  var database: Database
  var authenticated: Bool = false
  var password: String = ""

  override init()
  {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String

    database = Database("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
  }

  class func shared() -> AppDelegate!
  {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
  }

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
  {
    authenticated = false
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {}

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)
  {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("authView") as AuthController

    self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
      if self.window != nil
      {
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
      }
    })
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {}

  func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)
  {
    authenticated = false
  }

}
```